# Are Rails-style chained queries available in Grails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, grails, groovy, grails-orm, chaining

I am writing a scheduling feature in a new Grails 2.1.0 application. I am transitioning from a Ruby on Rails project, so much of my query strategy derives from Rails style. I have the following domain classes:

Schedule.groovy

```
class Schedule {

    // Number of minutes between available appointment slots
    int defaultAppointmentInterval
    Time officeOpenStart
    Time officeOpenEnd
    Time lunchStart
    Time lunchEnd

    static hasMany = [inventorySlots: InventorySlot]

    static constraints = {
       // long validation rules
    }

    def boolean isAvailableAt(Date dateTime) {
        def isAvailable = true
        if (inventorySlots.isEmpty()) {
            isAvailable = false
        } else if (inventorySlotsSurroundingTime(dateTime).isEmpty()) {
            isAvailable = false
        }
        isAvailable
    }

    def inventorySlotsSurroundingTime(Date dateTime) {
        InventorySlot.surroundingTime(dateTime) {
            and {
                inventorySlot.schedule = this
            }
        }
    }
}
```

InventorySlot.groovy

```
class InventorySlot {

    Date startTime

    static belongsTo = [schedule: Schedule]

    static constraints = {
        startTime nullable: false, blank: false
    }

    static mapping = {
        tablePerHierarchy true
        schedule lazy: false
    }

    static namedQueries = {}

    def static surroundingTime(Date time) {
        [UnboundedInventorySlot.surroundingTime(time), BoundedInventorySlot.surroundingTime(time)].flatten()
    }

    def endTime() {
        return ((BoundedInventorySlot) this).endTime?: (UnboundedInventorySlot (this)).endTime()
    }
}
```

UnboundedInventorySlot.groovy

```
class UnboundedInventorySlot extends InventorySlot {

    static namedQueries = {
    //        surroundingTime { time ->
    //            le 'startTime', time
    //            ge 'startTime', time - 1
    //        }
    }

    @Override
    def static surroundingTime(Date time) {
        findAllByStartTimeLessThanEqualsAndStartTimeGreaterThanEquals(time, time - 1)
    }

    def Date endTime() {
        def endTime

        // If the office closing is defined, use that, otherwise use tonight @ 23:59:59
        endTime = schedule?.officeOpenEnd?: new DateTime(startTime + 1).withTimeAtStartOfDay().plusSeconds(-1).toDate()

        return endTime
    }
}
```

BoundedInventorySlot.groovy

```
class BoundedInventorySlot extends InventorySlot {

    Date endTime

    static constraints = {
        endTime nullable: false, blank: false, validator: {val, obj ->
            if (val.date != obj.startTime.date) { return ["invalid.differentDate", val.date] }
        }
    }

    static namedQueries = {
    //        surroundingTime { time ->
    //            le 'startTime', time
    //            ge 'endTime', time
    //        }
    }

    @Override
    def static surroundingTime(Date time) {
        findAllByStartTimeLessThanEqualsAndEndTimeGreaterThanEquals(time, time)
    }


    @Override
    def Date endTime() {
        endTime
    }
}
```

What I would like to do is to implement the Schedule#isAvailableAt(Date) method as follows:

```
def boolean isAvailableAt(Date dateTime) {
    def isAvailable = true

    if (inventorySlots.isEmpty()) {
        isAvailable = false
    } else if (inventorySlots.surroundingTime(dateTime).isEmpty()) {
        isAvailable = false
    }

    isAvailable
}
```

where the `inventorySlots.surroundingTime()` invocation is essentially `InventorySlot.surroundingTime()` but instead of querying the universe of InventorySlots, it pre-filters on just the instances associated with the schedule instance. This is very common in Rails, but any searches for "chained query" or "collection query" in Grails doesn't seem to provide good documentation. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can think of two approaches off the top of my head which would work:

A more complex dynamic finder:

```
InventorySlots.findAllByScheduleAndStartTimeLessThanEqualsAndEndTimeGreaterThanEquals(this, time, time -1)
```

You can chain named queries together, then use any of the autowired finders to run the actual query, so if you uncomment your named query:

```
static namedQueries = {
        surroundingTime { time ->
            le 'startTime', time
            ge 'startTime', time - 1
        }
}
```

You could simply call:

`InventorySlots.surroundingTime(time).findAllBySchedule(this)`

You might also want to look into [*where* queries](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#whereQueries) in Grails 2 if you are not a fan of the criteria builder syntax. They are more type safe than criteria queries, and can be chained in the same fashion.

Update: Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with the inner workings of how named queries work with polymorphism, and I presume trouble with that is why you commented that out. I think worst case though, you could build a query on the parent like this one:

```
surroundingTime { time ->
            or {
                and {
                    eq('class', BoundedInventorySlot.name)
                    le 'startTime', time
                    ge 'startTime', time
                }
                and {
                    eq('class', UnboundedInventorySlot.name)
                    le 'startTime', time
                    ge 'startTime', time - 1
                }
            }
        }
```

***Update: Could you leverage the spread operator to simplify your task?  i.e. Keep this code, but remove the .flatten() and call surroundingTime as a named query or where query.

```
def static surroundingTime(Date time) {
        [UnboundedInventorySlot.surroundingTime(time), BoundedInventorySlot.surroundingTime(time)]
    }
```

Then you could call:
`Schedule.surroundingTime(time)*.findAllBySchedule(this).flatten()`

Not ideal that the caller needs to know to combine the results, but an interesting approach maybe.

Comment: There is a lot of helpful information here, so thank you. Unfortunately it does not seem to solve the problem I'm having. I've broken out how I worked around it and the problems with the various suggestions you provided.

As for the named query, "class" is not a property which can be queried (I also tried "className"). I added a `String type` field to the `InventorySlot` class and then used it as a discriminator column to query on the class type. However, because `endTime` is only declared in `BoundedInventorySlot`, it cannot be used in the `InventorySlot.surroundingTime` query.

Comment: With the dynamic finder method, again because `endTime` is only declared on `BoundedInventorySlot`, the parent class does not know how to handle it. I tried resolving this by moving `endTime` to the parent `InventorySlot` class definition. However, chaining the dynamic finders does not work because if the first clause returns an empty list, the list does not parse the next finder clause.

Comment: Using a single (long) dynamic finder does work, as shown below, but seems even more unwieldy than encapsulating that behavior in a static class method as I did originally. 

`void test() {
def nineToElevenSlot = new BoundedInventorySlot(//stuff)

def slotsFromStatic = InventorySlot.surroundingTime(tenAMToday)
def slotsFromDynamic = InventorySlot.findAllByStartTimeLessThanEqualsAndEndTimeGreaterThanEqualsAndSchedule(tenAMToday, tenAMToday, schedule)

assert slotsFromDynamic == slotsFromStatic
}`

Comment: Check my suggestion (still a bit unweildy, sadly).

Answer (score 0):

As a reference:

Query chaining in Grails' docs: http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#querying

See the "Query Composition" part.

Answer (score 0):

Adding an answer as this was the first search result. According to the docs, a where clause is a 'Detached Criteria'.

Example:

```
def query = Person.where {
     lastName == "Simpson"
}
def bartQuery = query.where {
     firstName == "Bart"
}
Person p = bartQuery.find()
```

[Where Query Composition](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#whereQueries)